# Add hovering effect for a child class when hover parent

Tags: javascript, css

I have a HTML structure like the following:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div>
    <span class="mui drop-down" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hover the `menu` class, and then change the color of `drop-down` class. And, also hovering the drop-down itself, it should also change its color. Currently I have:

```
.menu:hover,
.menu:hover ~ mui.drop-down{
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

but it doesn't do anything. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: You did not close off the double quotes on the 1st div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in both html/css:

1)`div` element with `menu` class miss closing quotes.

2)css selector `mui` miss `.`

According to your OP I think the following code is enough:

```css
.menu:hover .mui.drop-down {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">menu
  <div>
    <span class="mui drop-down">dropdown</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tilde (`~`) is the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Since there is a hierarchy, try the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) (`>`) or just a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) ():

```
.menu:hover mui.drop-down,
.menu:hover > div > mui.drop-down
{ color: #000000 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below css to hover effect:

```
.parent:hover .child, .parent.hover .child { display: block; }
```